# Node JS - Call js file function via command line

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi i have js file like below

var myfun = function(){
  return "string from function."
}

i Need command line like below

> node myfile.js myfun()

output : string from function.

how to achieve this?

Comment: Yes i have tried that but m running js file from node_module as like below

`node -e 'require(./node_modules/md-2-json/index.js).parse("#content")'`

Comment: Is your issue resolved.. ? If not, then you can try my answer posted below.

Comment: The problem is i used single quote instead of double quote..
`node -e "require(./node_modules/md-2-json/index.js).parse('#content')"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use [make-runnable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/make-runnable) you will need just to add `require('make-runnable');` at the end of the file and you can call it like `node myfile.js myfun`.

Or you can change `myfile.js` contents to:

```
module.exports.myFun = function () { return "string from function." };
```

and call it from the command line using this command:

```
node -e "console.log(require('./myfile.js').myFun())"
```

or even simpler, with this one:

```
node -p "require('./myfile.js').myFun()"
```

Comment: var s = node -e "console.log(require('./myfile.js').myFun())"
how to achieve this

Comment: I think it needs to be `module.exports.myFun`